# Install python for windows with no user interaction

Tags: python

How can I install Python on a windows machine from a batch script or something like that.

The requirement is that I need to install it with no human interaction.

and for site packages. Is it possible to install the packages found here also automated :

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pymatlab

Its basic .exe installers with some next clicks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unpack the contents of [Winpython](http://winpython.sourceforge.net/), copy this folder to any windows-machine you like. Your done :-).

Concerning your 2nd question: Winpython is fully portable and comes with a GUI-Installer for 3rd-party python packages. Install all you need ONLY ONCE and copy the Winpython folder afterwards to all Windows-PC.

Cheers barrios

EDIT: The Anaconda python package seems to have a portable mode, too. It comes preinstalled with many scientific packages. So it should also be possible to install all needed packages ONCE and move the whole Anaconda folder to all machines, but I havn't tested that, yet.

Comment: Please read my answer carefully: You install ALL packeges you need ONLY ONCE into the portable Winpythonfolder and simply COPY this folder to ALL machines you need! I guess that is what you want, isn't it?

Comment: Okay. I guess I can make that work. We wanted to install packages based on some config files dynamic, but guess we can install all packages and just copy paste in the files that are needed

Answer (score 1):

Python is just an .msi like any other. You install python like this, using the msi:

```
msiexec /i python-2.7.6.msi /passive
```

(use `/quiet` instead of `/passive` if you don't want any output at all.... `/passive` also requires no user input, but still shows the progress bar, which can be nice).

For 3rd party packages... if you can bootstrap distutils into the package (which you can do... check the distutils docs), you can use `easy_install`. If you point `easy_install` at a `tar.gz` file, it will use it instead of trying to download via pypi (though you can allow it to do that too, if you want). This also works if you point it at the exes from the site you mentioned. At least, most of them... there are occasional ones that are different (wxpython, pyreadline are two that I know of).

i.e.

```
c:\python27\scripts\easy_install.exe my_module.py27-amd64.exe
```

Comment: Possible to set the install location also ?

Comment: nvm,  found it TARGETDIR="C:\myfolder" /qb

Comment: there's also an option to install for all users, if you need that - the default is current user only, which is desired (some python modules e.g. comtypes won't find the python if it's installed for all users). just fyi.

Comment: I liked this one the most but ended up using the other answer because of problems getting some packages running on windows azure.

Comment: Please note that this works for Windows 7, but not for WinXP (broken in versions 2.7.3-2.7.10rc1)